# luigi: task runs other tasks without creating dependency?

Tags: dependencies, yield, luigi

In luigi, I understand that if a task yields to another task, the second task becomes a new dependency for the original task, and this causes the original task to be re-run after the yielded task completes.

However, in certain cases, I would like a task to defer to another task, without the deferred-to task becoming a dependency. The reason I want this is because I don't want my current task's `run` method to be re-run after the other task completes.

Yes, I know that my `run` method should be idempotent. Nonetheless, there are cases where I absolutely do not want that method to be run a second time after yielding to the other task.

I figured out a way to do this, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution, and I'd like some suggestions, if any of you have any.

Suppose that there are two tasks: `MainTask` and `OtherTask`. `MainTask` is invoked via the command line using various parameters. Depending on the settings of these parameters, `MainTask` might invoke `OtherTask`. If so, I do not want the `run` method of `MainTask` to be invoked a second time.

```
class OtherTask(luigi.Task):
    # Under some circumstances, this task can be invoked
    # from the command line, and it can also be invoked
    # in the normal luigi manner as a dependency for one
    # or more other tasks.
    # It also might be yielded to, as is done in the
    # "run" method for `MainTask`, below.

    id = luigi.parameter.IntParameter()

    def complete(self):
        # ...
        # return True or False depending on various tests.

    def requires(self):
        # return [ ... various dependencies ... ]

    def run(self):
        # do stuff with self.id
        # ...
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write('OK')

    def output(self):
        return '... something ...'

class MainTask(luigi.Task):
    # Parameters are expected to be supplied on the command line.
    param1 = luigi.parameter.IntParameter()
    param2 = luigi.parameter.BoolParameter()
    # ... etc. ...

    def run(self):
        #
        # Here's how I keep this "run" method from being
        # invoked more than once. Is there a better way
        # to invoke `OtherTask` without having it cause 
        # this current task to be re-invoked?
        if self.complete():
            return

        # Normal "run" processing for this task ...
        # ... etc. ...

        # Possibly run `OtherTask` multiple times, only if
        # certain conditions are met ... 
        tasks = []
        if the_conditions_are_met:
            ids = []
            # Append multiple integer ID's to the `ids` list.
            # Calculate each ID depending upon the values
            # passed in via self.param1, self.param2, etc.
            # Do some processing depending on these ID's.
            # ... etc. ...

            # Then, create a list of tasks to be invoked,
            # each one taking one of these ID's as a parameter.
            for the_id in ids:
                tasks.append(OtherTask(id=the_id))

        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write('OK')

        # Optionally yield after marking this task as 
        # complete, so that when the yielded tasks have
        # all run, this task's "run" method can test for
        # completion and not re-run its logic.
        if tasks:
            yield tasks

    def output(self):
        return '... whatever ...'
```

Comment: Actually, this only works in the case where all the yielded tasks succeed and don't need to be re-run, because it forces the completion test to be true after `MainTask` finishes the first time. It will appear to be complete if it is re-run, despite any yielded task failures.

Comment: The best way I came up with to handle this case is to take all of the logic out of the `run` method for `MainTask` and put it into the `run` method of a new `AuxiliaryTask` which is set up as a dependency to `MainTask`. `AuxiliaryTask` outputs the results of its calculations, and `MainTask` now simply reads that as input and yields to `OtherTask`. Perhaps this is the only way to make this work properly, but I'm still hoping for a way for one task to defer to another, without the first task's `run` method being re-invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment, using an auxiliary class seems to work. It will only run once, and even if the main class's `run` method is invoked more than once, it just reuses the output data from the auxiliary class without it being recalculated.

```
class OtherTask(luigi.Task):
    # Under some circumstances, this task can be invoked
    # from the command line, and it can also be invoked
    # in the normal luigi manner as a dependency for one
    # or more other tasks.
    # It also might be yielded to, as is done in the
    # "run" method for `MainTask`, below.

    id = luigi.parameter.IntParameter()

    def complete(self):
        # ...
        # return True or False depending on various tests.

    def requires(self):
        # return [ ... various dependencies ... ]

    def run(self):
        # do stuff with self.id
        # ...
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write('OK')

    def output(self):
        return '... something ...'

class AuxiliaryTask(luigi.Task):

    def requires(self):
        # return [ ... various dependencies ... ]

    def run(self):                
        ids = []
        # Append multiple integer ID's to the `ids` list.
        # Calculate each ID depending upon the values
        # passed to this task via its parameters. Then ...
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(ids))

    def output(self):
        return '... something else ...' 

class MainTask(luigi.Task):
    # Parameters are expected to be supplied on the command line.
    param1 = luigi.parameter.IntParameter()
    param2 = luigi.parameter.BoolParameter()
    # ... etc. ...

    def requires(self):
        return [ self.clone(AuxiliaryTask) ]

    def run(self):
        # This method could get re-run after the yields,
        # below. However, it just re-reads its input, instead
        # of that input being recalculated. And in the second
        # invocation, luigi's dependency mechanism will prevent
        # any re-yielded-to tasks from repeating what they did
        # before.
        ids = []
        with self.input().open('r') as f:
            ids = json.dumps(f.read())

        if ids:
            tasks = []

            # Create a list of tasks to be invoked,
            # each one taking one of these ID's as a parameter.
            # Then, yield to each of these tasks.
            for the_id in ids:
                tasks.append(OtherTask(id=the_id))
            if tasks:
                yield tasks

        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            f.write('OK')


    def output(self):
        return '... whatever ...'
```